# “WARN hdfs.DFSUtil: Namenode for null remains unresolved for ID null.”

Tags: hadoop

I want to test if my hadoop worked well after configuration, but after the input, the command   **start-all.sh**   show below error in terminal

> WARN hdfs.DFSUtil: Namenode for null remains unresolved for ID null. 
>   Check your hdfs-site.xml file to ensure namenodes are configured
>   properly.
>       Starting namenodes on [master]
>       master: ssh: Could not resolve hostname master: Name or service not known

I checked my **hdfs-site.xml** file and resolved it as others given like this

```
<configuration>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
      <value>master:50090</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
      <value>file:/home/lidekanfa/tools/hadoop-2.7.7/hdfs/name</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
      <value>file:/home/lidekanfa/tools/hadoop-2.7.7/hdfs/data</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

It still doesn't work. Then I checked my hosts file and I have given the ip and name ,and more I can log in the **slave** without password. What is the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer. There are 2 points.

First, my **master's name** called lidekanfa, not master. But in **hdfs-site.xml** file and other configuration files where should use **master's name**(lidekanfa), I used master instead. So it warns  Namenode for null remains unresolved for ID null.

Second, There is an another hidden problem for me. In the installation tutorials for beginner, they use the same user name such as root etc among machines, but I didn't notice that. This lead the problem that after I fixed the problem mentioned above, it called me to input the password, but the user name and the ID didn't match, so the hadoop didn't work. To solve this problem, I reproduce the keys and start hadoop with root identity. Meanwhile, you may rewrite the sshd_config file to allow login as root. You can also solve this problem use the same user name among machines.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem.The problem was with my `core-site.xml`. after correcting the `localhost`, it worked fine. `Namenode` was able to connect the localhost.
In my case

```
error core-site.xml : <value>hdfs://localhosts:9000</value>

corrected core-site.xml : <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
```